# Get selected value from database table?

Tags: php, mysql

im new in field of manipulating databases so i have a problem.
So after making a query to select all values from a table row with something like :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { }
```

For example if table has names in it we would get :

```
John
Bob
Steve
Mark
```

If we put these results in a form of a link or a button, is there any way to get their value?

i tried something like :

```
if (isset($_POST['result_button'])) {
$value =$row['name'];
}
```

I tried this when i put all the results from query in to a form of button, but that only pulls the last value from table row.

I tried putting results into array like :

```
$result= array();
$result[]=$row['name'];

echo $result[2];
```

I don't fully understand how arrays works so might have done something wrong there but from what i tried this works only if i put `echo`$result[0];

Comment: You have laid out the question adequately, however you've left out the most important bit, the query. Please include an entire chunk of your code including the query, something we can run and execute ourselves perhaps. If you are having trouble with arrays this will help us identify other issues that might be getting in the way. What you are asking seems trivial, we want to help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, firstly:

`$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

This does not work how you're expecting it to. What this is basically saying, is that for *each* returned value (from the MySQL query), store in `$row` for this iteration of the while loop.

So, in you're example, `$row` will first be John, then Bob, then Steve and finally Mark. They are not all stored in the variable at the same time. Bob overwrites John, etc.

I'm going to skip your second bit of code, as it's clear you do not have an understanding of `arrays`.

**Arrays**

There is plenty of material about arrays on the web. I'm not sure why you had to post the question here, however...

To define an array:

```
$my_array = array();
```

An array with values:

```
$my_array = array(
    "bar",
    "foo"
);
```

Assign variables to an array:

```
$my_array = array();
$my_array[0] = "Help" // $my_array[0] now contains "Help"
$my_array[1] = "Me"; // $my_array[0] now contains "Me"
```

So, taking you're final example:

```
$result= array();
$result[]=$row['name'];

echo $result[2];
```

You haven't stored anything in the 2nd element of the array.

This would be more appropriate:

```
$result= array();
$result[0] = $row['name'];

echo $result[0]; // This would print what was stored in $row['name']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining ! This is great!